# Inquirer.js: ask multiple questions if one prompt is true

Tags: node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

I'm writing an account creator using Inquirer.js, and wanted to ask for the user's e-mail and password only if the user asked for such protection. It goes like this:

```js
inquirer.prompt([
        {type:'input', name:'username', message:'Choose an username:'}, 
        {type:'confirm', name:'protect_ask', message:'Do you want to password-protect your game list?'},
        {type:'input', name:'email', message:'E-mail (for password recovering):', when:function(answers){return answers.protect_ask}},
        {type:'password', name:'password', message:'Password:', when:function(answers){return answers.protect_ask}},
        {type:'password', name:'confirm_password', message:'Confirm you password:', when:function(answers){return answers.protect_ask}}
    ]
```

As you can see, I'm running the exact same *when* statement three times, for it verifies if the password-protection was chosen or not. **I want to know if there's a more intelligent, pragmatic way to do so, this is, to run this verification without repeating the *when* function.**

Maybe nesting the three questions would do it, but how to do so without breaking the prompt flow?